# How to install macOS software from source to mitigate Spectre 2?

Tags: macos, make, macos-highsierra, spectre

I attended a [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m66EAgRMmi8) on Spectre and Meltdown by a UCL professor. He suggested several ways to mitigate Spectre 2 (Branch Target Injection) by upgrading to High Sierra and installing all software from source with the switch --mretpoline (already deployed in LLVM and GCC). I want to install R and RStudio on macOS High Sierra this way. I downloaded the source for both. The installation procedure is similar for R and RStudio. The file INSTALL for R says that I should run

```
./configure
make
```

I inspected the “configure” file and the makefiles (Makeconf.in, Makefile.in, Makefile.in). I saw no obvious way to add the switch. I called the help for make, which also does not mention how to add a switch.

I searched for this online and the closest I could find was explanations of retpoline and Spectre 2.

How can I compile software from source with make and include the --mretpoline switch?

Comment: Just to avoid confusion there is also a SO question for this (by you) that was closed. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523008/how-to-install-software-with-make-and-mretpoline). Also [Passing additional variables from command line to make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make) might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks @Seth for the link to avoid confusion and for the tip on passing variables. The passing of variables works, but not the particular flag `-mretpoline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version**: After much investigation, I was unable to install software on MacOS from source with either `llvm` and `-mretpoline` flag, or with `gcc` and `-mindirect-branch=thunk -mfunction-return=thunk -mindirect-branch-register` flags. This seems more general than `R` and specific to `MacOS`, so I changed the title accordingly. I suspect that this cannot be done on a Mac as of 27 April 2018. I am running macOS High Sierra version 10.13.3 (17D102).

**Long version**: The following applies to GnuPG, which I decided to install before R (because R requires gfortran, which requires gcc, which requires [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org), which comes with a GPG signature that I wanted to verify). I followed the [steps to install GPG from Git](https://www.gnupg.org/download/git.html).

#### Latest LLVM (with Homebrew)

LLVM from Apple fails (see below), so I used LLVM clang 6 to fix this and I installed with homebrew (it defeats a bit the purpose of compiling from source with specific flags, but I was running out of time). I installed homebrew with:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then updated it twice with

```
brew update
```

Installing clang with Homebrew required XCode, so I installed that from the App Store. Then I followed the steps at [this page](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/2/20/installing-clangllvm-on-osx):

```
brew install --with-toolchain llvm
```

Then I added the `-mretpoline` flag to both `C`, I added the path to both `C` and `C++` compilers, and I called the shell scripts from GPG:

```
export CFLAGS='-mretpoline'
export CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
./autogen.sh
./configure --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-maintainer-mode  && make
```

I got this error:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

The log file `config.log` gives more details:

```
configure:4049: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -mretpoline   conftest.c  >&5
fatal error: error in backend: MachO doesn't support COMDATs, '__llvm_retpoline_r11' cannot be lowered.
clang-6.0: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[This thread](https://reviews.llvm.org/D41723) with a comment from January 2018 at the bottom saying that Mac is not yet supported with `-mretpoline`:

> samkellett: @chandlerc is MacOS support omitted intentionally (ie. not implemented yet)?
>   chandlerc: Not at all, I just don't have a Mac system to test with...

It has no response since then. So installing with LLVM failed.

#### GCC (with Homebrew)

Another alternative was to compile with `gcc` instead of LLVM. I installed the latest version of clang (6.0) with

```
brew install gcc
```

And I added the `gcc` flags from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428351/how-to-mitigate-spectre-with-gcc-and-clang-or-llvm-in-general), which are different from LLVM. This bash script adds the flags to both `C` and `C++`, gives the paths to both compilers, and call the shell scripts from GPG:

```
export CFLAGS='-mindirect-branch=thunk -mfunction-return=thunk -mindirect-branch-register'
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export CC=/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gcc-7
export CXX=/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/g++-7
./autogen.sh
./configure --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-maintainer-mode  && make
```

and again I get the error:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

The log file `config.log` gives more details:

```
configure:4027: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4049: /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gcc-7 -mindirect-branch=thunk -mfunction-return=thunk -mindirect-branch-register   conftest.c  >&5
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__x86_return_thunk", referenced from:
      _main in ccZuBhFQ.o
     (maybe you meant: ___x86_return_thunk)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:4053: $? = 1
configure:4091: result: no
```

It's weird that the compiler knows about the similar sounding name with an extra underscore.

So `gcc` failed too. And now I'm at a loss.

#### Appendix: LLVM from Apple

The following bash script exports the flags for `make` and calls the shell scripts from GnuPG:

```
export CFLAGS='-mretpoline'
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
echo $CFLAGS
echo $CXXFLAGS
./autogen.sh
./configure --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-maintainer-mode  && make
```

It fails with the compiler that ships from Apple, but it shows that the flags are getting through to the compiler:

```
configure:4045: gcc -mretpoline -mindirect-branch=thunk -mfunction-return=thunk -mindirect-branch-register   conftest.c  >&5
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mretpoline'
```

So @seth's comment is right in how to send flags to the compiler.